# My parallax is laggy and I've built it with CSS only

Tags: html, css, parallax, lag

I thought making my parallax CSS only would make things less laggy, but seems not. If you wanna check out the code and tell me if there's something done poorly, I'd be thankful.

the html:

```
<div class="parallax">  
<div id="up">

    <div class="spacer"></div>

        <div id="intro">

            <h1>A studio made up of   </h1>
            <h2 class="future-animate">  1</h2>
            <div class="animate"></div>
            <h1> person,</h1>

        </div>

    <div class="spacer"></div>

</div>
```

the css:

```
.parallax {
/* The image used */
background: url('bgintro.jpg');

/*sizing height */
height: 799px; 
width: 100%;

/* Creating the parallax scrolling effect */
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
float: left;
display: inline-block;
z-index: -1;
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width:1024px) {
.parallax{
    background-attachment: scroll;
 }
 }
```

and the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/ovyhttgw/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your code is working fine what's wrong ??

Comment: Really? Okay, thanks for the input, I'll have to look into other probabilities

Comment: There's no lag because you've fixed your background rather than moving it slower than the rest of the content.